# The meaning of the "Score" in ScanProsite

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, protein-binding

I'm doing some research about a proteïne which is sequenced, however Í'm not able to find any information about the score which ProSite scan shows after finding an possible domain profile.
[image]

I have read the [prosite help](http://prosite.expasy.org/scanprosite/scanprosite_doc.html#of_graphical), however there isn't anything which explains what the score means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The score provides an indication of well a specific profile (which is a weight matrix) matches the profile for the domain. [**Section II.B. Profiles development** explains this in further detail.](http://prosite.expasy.org/prosuser.html#conv_nr)

[A paper that outlines the development of PROSITE](http://bib.oxfordjournals.org/content/3/3/265.full.pdf+html) notes that they primarily use a cut-off of 8.5 and explains the score thus;

> the raw scores in PROSITE profiles are converted into so-called ‘log10
>   per residue E-values’, allowing the computation of the number of
>   expected matches with equal or higher score in a database of a given
>   size. For instance **a match with a normalised score of 9.0 or higher is
>   expected to occur about once in a database of one billion residues**.

Comment: Why isn't it just an E-value just like in BLAST? I read your references but I can't get it clear. Do you know how it's calculated? @Michael_A

Comment: The paper that I linked to outlines how the E-values are calculated and it also provides an explanation for why they used this approach.